# Google Drive API JAVA User Class

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am trying to get the name of the authorized user of google drive using this code :

```
public class list extends HttpServlet{

    private DbxClient client;
    String token;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException, IOException{

        try{
            DbxRequestConfig requestConfig = new 
            DbxRequestConfig("JavaDropBoxTutorial/1.0",Locale.getDefault().toString() );

            HttpSession session = req.getSession();
            token = session.getAttribute("access_token").toString();

            client = new DbxClient(requestConfig, token);

                    session.setAttribute("dropuser",client.getAccountInfo().displayName);

            User u = new User();
            System.out.print(u.getDisplayName());

            res.sendRedirect("listdetails.jsp");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this Error : -

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

With the exception

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions

Comment: m trying to get the name of the authorized user of google drive

Comment: Please consider reducing your code example to a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and improving the formatting to make it a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your `code` and `Error` not clearing question but you may be looking for below(as per comment) :

Use below code to get user name of authorized user of google drive :

```
  try {
      About about = service.about().get().execute();
      System.out.println("Current user name: " + about.getName());

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
    }
```

[**You  can get more details Here**](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get)